# Image change when i scroll listview

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app , i load images from `url` and display it in `imageview` using `listview` 
but when i scroll the `listview` the `image` change.

Here is my code:

**List Adapter:**

```
class DataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArtistClass>{
    public DataAdapter() {
        super(Activity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,datalist);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View item=convertView;
        if(item==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            item=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, parent,false);
        }

        ArtistClass p=datalist.get(position);

     TextView artistnametxt=(TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.artistnametxt);
     ImageView artistimage=(ImageView)item.findViewById(R.id.artistimage);
        String ospartistname=p.getartistname();
        artistnametxt.setText(ospartistname);
        String artistimageurl=p.getartistimage();
        new DownloadImageTask(artistimage).execute(artistimageurl);

        return (item);

    }

}
```

and its function to load images from url:

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its becoz you load image asynchronusly. which means when image loading completes at that time listview adapter use old imageView to hold and display image.

you should always set null OR some default image to imageiew before set bitmaps.

```
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    bmImage.setImageResource(null);
    bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
}
```

as per my suggesion you should instead use image loading library like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Piccaso](https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-getting-started-simple-loading).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not use listview, instead, use the new RecyclerView.
With a recyclerview you can create a dedicaded ViewHolder foreach itens in your data.

Second, you need cache the Bitmap after its loaded, when the item is not on screen, the views and bitmaps are recycled for reuse when the views is on screen again, but the holder loses the bitmap reference and automatically set a "random" bitmap located on some views.

To prevent this, create or use the cache class LruCache for example.

References:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html
http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html